# Can't get UITextFieldDelegate to work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I write a custom view `CustomViewA : UIView<UITextFieldDelegate>`and implements the delegate's methods.

And in the CustomViewA's init I write:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewA" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (self) {
        //the txtfieldA is a IBOutlet property linked to the nib file.
        self.txtfieldA.delegate = self; //not work
    }
    return  self;
}
```

And in this **xib** file includes a **UITextField** control which I set its delegate in the `init` method.But when I run this and edit the textfield, the delegate's methods are **not** called.Can anyone tell me why? And how can I fix it??

Comment: Please post your entire init method

Comment: Also, please post the code that creates and uses CustomViewA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a view which subclass an UIView from a xib file, you can do this way:

```
// Reusable method to load a class which subclass UIView from a xib.
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName ofClass:(Class)objClass andOwner:(id)owner {
    if (nibName && objClass) {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:owner options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in objects ){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:objClass])
                return currentObject;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then add the view in your controller:

```
myCustomViewA = [self loadNibNamed:@"customviewA" ofClass:[CustomViewA class] andOwner:self];

myCustomViewA.delegate = self; // Or do this in the xib file
[self.view addSubview:myCustomViewA];
```

Comment: I donnot know if there is any different between `self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewA" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];` and yours `NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:owner options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in objects ){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:objClass])
                return currentObject;
        }`? Can you explain me the details?

Comment: With my way, I really check the type of the view that I get. If you take the object at index 0 you do not really know if the view has the type that you want. I agree with you, your method works, but this is too dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that that the `UITextField` is correctly wired to the `IBOutlet` of of CustomViewA.
Otherwise, attempting to set the delegate in `init` will do nothing,

```
//if self.myTextField is nil, then this does nothing
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply do not use -(id)init if you init a view from xib files.

and set your UITextField's delegate method in `- (void)awakeFromNib.`.

Comment: I do as you said, no use.
`- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.tvSizeMax.delegate = self;
    self.tvSizeMin.delegate = self;
}
`

Comment: how do you init CustomViewA ? `CustomViewA *cusomViewA = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewA" owner:self options:nil] lastObject]`,`then cusomViewA.delegate = self.view(where you add cusomViewA as subView)` ,only in this way you get the `- (void)awakeFromNib` invoked.

Comment: also i'm confused by `self.tvSizeMax`and `self.tvSizeMin`,are they UITextField?